# Get only the module name, without the path

Tags: c++, winapi

Using the `GetModuleFileName` function I get the path and the module name. So if the module path is `C:\Users\user\Desktop\file.exe` I only want to get the `file.exe`, without the whole path. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: [std::filesystem::path::filename](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/filename)?

Comment: For MSVC there's also the [`_splitpath_s`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/splitpath-s-wsplitpath-s?view=msvc-160) CRT function.

Comment: use `wcsrchr` with \ and / or [`PathFindFileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathfindfilenamew)